# How to get a proper/better image from Sentinel?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, sentinel2

I am following the code from [Sentinel Hub](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ogc_request.html) but if I chose my bbox to be somewhere else, like Greenland or Antartica, my image doesn't show or shows only some parts of it. It looks like the resolution isn't right or perhaps my bbox coordinates are wrong. I am getting box coordinates from http://bboxfinder.com/, not sure if that is the best way. This is my code:

```
my_coords = [-73.297, 60.03676, -12.20855, 83.64513]
my_bbox = BBox(bbox=my_coords, crs=CRS.WGS84)

wms_true_color_request = WmsRequest(
    layer='TRUE-COLOR-S2-L1C',
    bbox=my_box,
    time=('2018-01-01', '2019-01-02'),
    height=500,
    width=800,
    config=config
)

wms_true_color_img = wms_true_color_request.get_data()

def plot_image(image, factor=1):
    """
    Utility function for plotting RGB images.
    """
    fig = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 7))

    if np.issubdtype(image.dtype, np.floating):
        plt.imshow(np.minimum(image * factor, 1))
    else:
        plt.imshow(image)

plot_image(wms_true_color_img[3])
```

There are around 200 images for this period, say I pick the third one, I get:

[image: Output of the plot above]

It doesn't look right. Any ideas on how to improve this?